Messages do not appear when snort prints out in json format
I am using the code below in Snort to get JSON output, but the messages that should be generated by Snort are not appearing in the output. They do appear when using alert_fast. How can I configure it to include the messages?
sudo snort -c /etc/snort/snort.lua -r -A alert_json -q
I was expecting the alert messages generated by Snort to be visible in the .JSON format as well.
